# Standard for generating Mnemonic words for wallets

Tags: wallets, secret-key

Is there a particular BIP standard that is recommended for generating mnemonic? Tezbridge and Conseiljs-softsigner both utilises BIP39 but I understand that BIP44 is also being used. Which one should we follow?

Answer (score 0):

Normally we all use BIP39,  it is the standard tz1 address